# LasDatasetToRaster does nothing to the Raster Layer

Tags: raster, arcobjects, c#, lidar

I have been trying to figure out how to clip and rasterize a LiDAR map file programmatically (Not through `arcpy`) I use C# but read many languages. So far I have been able to access and assign the LASD values but when I use `ILasSurface.AsRaster` or `LasDatasetToRaster` the RasterLayer outputs the same black square as if I did not call these functions. I can't find any documentation on this so I hope somebody can help.

```
    public void RasterDatasetToMap(IRasterDataset rDataset, IPointFilter pf, IRasterDatasetLayer pRasterLayer)
    {
        ISpatialReference sr = new UnknownCoordinateSystemClass();
        ITrackCancel2 tc = new CancelTrackerClass();
        //Define the position and dimension of the raster dataset.
        IPoint origin = new PointClass();
        origin.PutCoords(15.0, 15.0);

        int width = 100; //This is the width of the raster dataset.
        int height = 100; //This is the height of the raster dataset.
        double xCell = 30; //This is the cell size in x direction.
        double yCell = 30; //This is the cell size in y direction.
        int NumBand = 1;

        //Create new Raster Dataset
        try
        {
            rDataset = rWorkshop.CreateRasterDataset(
                "new raster layer - test 9", "TIFF", //filename and format
                origin, width, height, xCell, yCell, //Dimensions
                NumBand, rstPixelType.PT_FLOAT, sr, //Pixels, Spacial Reference
                true //Permenant?
            );
            status += "Default RasterDatabase Set! \n";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status += "Failed to create raster dataset: " + ex.Message + " " + status + "\n";
        }


        //Set Point Filter
        try
        {
            pf = (ILasFilter)new LasFilter();
            pf.AreaOfInterest = aview.Extent.Envelope;
            status += "Point Filter Set! \nDimensions: " + pf.AreaOfInterest.Envelope.Height + "x" + pf.AreaOfInterest.Envelope.Width + "\n";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status += "Failed to create point filter: " + ex.Message + " " + status + "\n";
        }

        //Rasterize Raster Dataset
        try
        {
            /*
             * Possible Methods
             */

            LASSurface.AsRaster(
                tc, //Track Cancel
                pf, //Point Filter
               rDataset, //Output Raster Dataset
               //Rastering Options
               esriPointToRasterMethod.esriPointToRasterNearest,
               esriLasZSource.esriLasZSourceZ,
               esriPointToRasterVoidFillMethod.esriPointToRasterVoidFillInterpolation,
               esriSurfaceInterpolationType.esriLinearInterpolation,
               1
            );

            /*LasDatasetToRaster conversion = new LasDatasetToRaster(
                LASDatasetLayer,
                rDataset
            );*/
            status += "Rastering technique finished. Check map for validity. \n";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status += "Failed to  raster dataset: " + ex.Message + " " + status + "\n";
        }

        //Experiment
        try
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status += "Failed to  create tin: " + ex.Message + " " + status + "\n";
        }

        //Create Raster Layer
        try
        {
            pRasterLayer = new RasterLayer();
            pRasterLayer.CreateFromDataset(rDataset);
            status += "Default RasterLayer Set! \n";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status += "Failed to create raster layer: " + ex.Message + " " + status + "\n";
        }

        map.AddLayer(pRasterLayer);
        status += "Check Your Map! \n";
    }
```

Comment: So, do you already have multiple las files embedded in a las dataset (.lasd)? Are you trying to rasterize the entire point cloud, or just one class of it, for example, points belonging to the ground? Are the las files classified into ground and non ground? I don't know if this is related to the question, nor I understand C#. I am just trying to comprehend in more details what you are doing. Tks.

Comment: I have one embedded file and I am ultimately trying to cut out a geometric raster from the LASD. Right now I am just trying to get the RasterDataset to work.